# What files should a preloaded sd card have on it?

Tags: raspbian

I was wondering what exactly a preloaded raspberry pi card should have on it? We purchased one but my father was tinkering around on it and I think some of the file were removed but I'm not sure what is missing..

Comment: What makes you think files are missing?

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the common linux distros, there are two partitions in the image.  The first contains a small vfat filesystem (50-60 MB) with a single directory of a few files such as:

```
bootcode.bin
cmdline.txt
config.txt
fixup_cd.dat
fixup.dat
fixup_x.dat
issue.txt
kernel.img
start_cd.elf
start.elf
start_x.elf
```

Very likely there is also an `overlays` directory and a handful of `.dtb` files.

The second partition is a much larger and contains an ext4 filesystem with a set of top level directories like this:

```
bin
boot
dev
etc
home
lib
lost+found
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
selinux
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

Some of which are empty mountpoints -- e.g., the first partition is in `/boot` when the system is running.

**However**, if you are looking at the card on a windows machine you will not be able to see the second partition, so it may appear as if there is not much there.